# smooth shading issues after booleaning cylinder

Tags: modifiers, shaders

i was trying to make a hole in cylinder part of my object, but then i faced a problem. after adding a modifier, shading issues became visible (like on a picture). what am i supposed to do?

[image: shading issue]

Comment: Bools often create poor topology. They can't just "imprint" into the middle of a face, they must choose a point (or more) on a nearby edge to "connect" the cut to. You will have to correct the bad topology in order to get proper shading.

Comment: Josh Gambrell on Youtube has some terrific tutorials on just this sort of issue.  His channel:  https://www.youtube.com/channel/UCXfGjwohMgPm4Ng2e1FXySw

Comment: Just wanted to add: If you're using a bevel modifier after the boolean, you can select "Harden Normals" (or add a weighted normals modifier) and that can sometimes clear up shading issues like this. Another thing to check is to make sure Angle mode is turned on in the bevel, so only very hard edges get beveled. Everyone else here is correct though - clean up is necessary after boolean operations to minimize double verts and wonky topology.